# Class "AGConnectServicesConfig" is deprecated in com.huawei.hms:push:5.3.0.301

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

When I updated the pushSDK to the version "5.3.0.301", I found `AGConnectServicesConfig` was deprecated. I want to know what is the substitute for it. How can I get app_id in the new version?
I used to get app_id like this:

```
  String appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(context).getString("client/app_id");
```

How can I get it when I update?

**I have found the source code**, but I can't find any substitute for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

[image]

```
 String appId = new AGConnectOptionsBuilder().build(MainActivity.this).getString("client/app_id");
```

For more details,check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agccore-agconnectoptions-0000001116446037?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: I'm sorry, I update to version 5.3.0.301. it was deprecated in version 5.3.0.301, not version 5.0.4.302. And I know that AGConnectServicesConfig still exists in the pushSDK 5.3.0.301 version.I just found it was deprecated, So i want to find new class to substitute for it.how can i get app_id in version 5.3.0.301？ If there is nothing to substitute for it, why you set it deprecated. Otherwise your demo is still version 5.0.4.302，I suggest updating to the newest version。Thank you.

Comment: hi@Shadowself, i updated my answer,you can try that.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is:

Step-1 : Dependency version was updated.

```
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.1.0.300'
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'
```

Step-2 : This was changed.

```
AGConnectOptionsBuilder().build(this@MainActivity)
                    .getString("client/app_id")
```

It's worked.